# how to resolve nginx static assets not found error

Tags: python, nginx, flask

my application is working fine at

```
location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/socket_file.sock;
}
```

but when i include static assets location `location ~* .\(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rtf)`it gives 404 not found error for css,js files

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
    location ~* \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rtf)$ {
       expires max;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/socket_file.sock;
    }
}
```

nginx error log show `

> "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/jspdf.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
> '
> While my static assets are in  /ProjectDirectory/assets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`location`s are mutually exclusive,** i.e. only one may match at a time. When the first location (regex) matches, directives in the second location `/` are ignored, and Nginx will proceed with whatever defined *outside* of this location block (if not defined). In your case, it's apparent that `root /usr/share/nginx/html` is defined somewhere at an outer level.

A straightforward solution would be to add the same `include` and `uwsgi_pass` to the first location block, but since you're serving static files, why not let Nginx handle it by adding `root /path/to/your/static/files`?

In practice, instead of matching file extension by regex, it's better to put all your files in one location, and use prefix-based matching:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /ProjectDirectory/assets/;
}
```

You might want to read [this answer](/a/10647080/5958455) to learn about the differences between `root` and `alias`.

Comment: Thanks @iBug for your help it worked by adding **uwsgi_pass** and **uwsgi_params**